# Accused of being dishonest for not informing a professor of a clerical error she made

Tags: academic-life

One of my professors returned an assignment that was graded by hand. After the semester ended and the final grades were submitted, the professor discovered that the grade was incorrectly entered in the online grade book as 95/100 instead of 73/100. She is now motioning to have the grade changed and has also filed an academic integrity violation complaint for my failure to inform her of this as she is convinced I must have checked my grade and deliberately not made her aware of the error. But I had already seen the grade on the physical copy and did not see why I should check the online grade. Also, I am not responsible for a clerical error on the professor's part.

Do I have a case if this goes before the academic integrity committee or am I responsible?

Comment: I would think you do have a case, and that the situation would never get to a hearing. Stranger things have happened though, so see what your options are for assistance/representation in any hearings.

Comment: If you present your case the right way, I also think you have a case. However, I’m not sure that saying “I am not responsible for a clerical error on the professor’s part” would count as presenting your case the right way. That’s essentially saying “even if I was dishonest, you cannot fault me because you yourself committed an error (that did not involve any dishonesty)”. Justice doesn’t work that way. You have a case _only if_ you can create a reasonably credible impression that you actually were not dishonest.

Comment: See also this commonly asked legal question analogous to your situation: [1](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2012/sep/25/fraud-accept-too-much-change), [2](https://www.quora.com/If-a-cashier-gives-me-the-wrong-change-am-I-obligated-to-give-it-back), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/27ruev/is_it_illegal_to_knowingly_accept_the_wrong/), [4](https://japantoday.com/category/crime/woman-arrested-for-pocketing-change-given-to-her-by-mistake).

Comment: So if it were the other way around (73/100 entered in the online grade book vs 95/100 physical grade), would you not have noticed?

Comment: @mmeent I don't know about OP, but I have never cross checked a grade in my life. The first time I'd have noticed is when I needed to submit a transcript for an application. Even then, I'd only notice a really big change.

Comment: What do the academic integrity rules in your university or program say? If there is an item that students are required to cross-check their results and inform about issues in either direction, you have a problem. If not, I see no reasonable way how the professor would convince an academic integrity committee that this is your problem.

Comment: My practice when I was teaching was that an error I made would never reduce a student's grade, but could increase it.  If I were your professor, you'd have gotten the 95% that *I* typed into the computer.  (I know that is of little comfort, but you should know that some, probably most, do as I did.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable that you didn't cross check your grades against some online portal. I never did that. Often after an exam, I was too focused on extracting myself from the stress to even look at the papers that I got back. It was better for my mental health to assume the marks were reasonable. Not saying this is good practice, but there are reasons besides laziness for not following up on exam marks.

Do you have a student union? If so, this is almost certainly something they would be able to help you with. If there is no student union, perhaps approach a friendly faculty member, and let them know what's happening.

The professor who insists you are being duplicitous is being unreasonable, so hopefully nothing will come of it.

I also agree with Dan Romik, that you really mustn't say “I am not responsible for a clerical error on the professor’s part”. Dan is right, that it almost sounds like an admission of having looked at the online portal. Furthermore, despite the professor's poor behaviour, you would be better off not saying anything that could be seen as critical of them, or anyone else in the university. Many people are uncomfortable hearing criticism of their collogues, so it may well not get a good reaction.

Have a quick look in the syllabus and student handbook to see if you were supposed to verify your grades in the online portal.
When you are asked about it, simply explain that you did not compare marks with those in the online portal. If you were supposed to check, apologise for the lapse, otherwise, just say that you are surprised that anyone would expect you to check.

Comment: Something for the OP to double check is if there in fact is any expectation of checking the grades (university policy, something in the syllabus). Seems kind of unlikely, but...

Comment: @JonCuster good point.

Comment: When I used "student union" none of the students understood what I meant. Sometimes this is called "student government" or "student government association" instead. YMMV.

Comment: @PeterK. Especially because in the US "student union" has morphed on many campuses to refer to a *building* that contains meeting rooms, dining options, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a case for several torts, one of which is libel.

I would recommend writing a carefully worded letter.  Have someone with a bit of experience look it over and edit it for you.

In this letter, lay out all of the facts that are not in dispute.  Write it in a chronological fashion.  Start from the basics of what class this is, the current semester, when you took the exam, when you received the graded exam, etc.  Be as thorough as possible.  If you did not check the online grade at all, then mention this.  As well, verify that it is not codified anywhere that you are responsible for ensuring that the grades online and on paper align.  Mention this.  Be entirely truthful throughout the letter.

Make sure to note that knowingly and willfully making false academic integrity complaints is either defamation or defamation per se.  As well, making false claims, without verifying them, is negligent.  If such claims are made, then you have legal remedies and will pursue for such actions.  After all, they are a blight on your otherwise, hopefully, unblemished academic career.

You will need an attorney to tell you if this is defamation per se or not. If it is, and your state recognizes it, then you will not have to prove that you suffered damages.

Once you are done writing this letter, contact a few attorneys in your area that practice civil law.  Most will do an initial consultation for free.  Some will charge a small fee for this, usually about an hour or two of their hourly rate.  If none of them will do it for free, then pay the fee and listen to what they have to say.  Email the letter to the attorney after they agree to an initial consult, since it outlines all of the facts in a concise way for them.  As well, make sure that you have the email addresses of the professor and her department chair, along with the physical mailing addresses for their offices.  Basically, think of everything you can do to make the life of your attorney easy.  You can even start doing your own case law studies through a number of sites; casetext, for example, offers free access for most universities.

If you have a case, then most attorneys will be willing to write and send a target letter on your behalf.  They'll charge about an hour or two for this. It may be a little more if either they have to or a junior attorney has to do a case law survey.

You could certainly send the letter that you wrote.  However, having an attorney send one to both the professor, her department chair, or whomever the attorney recommends is a much stronger response.  It shows that you are serious about these false accusations and will take measures to protect yourself against them.

The professor will do one of two things.  The first is that she will, foolishly, double down.  At that point, everything she says and does will just make your case easier, especially if and when depositions are taken.  The second is that she will, rightfully, be embarrassed, realize that she made a mistake, overreacted, and drop the matter.

Comment: Tell me you're an American without telling me you're an American... (no offense meant to the majority of Americans whose first thought in every single situation is not to reach for a lawyer)

Comment: @Adam Přenosil: The first thought of the typical American is not to invoke a superior authority, but to worry about the other guy invoking a superior authority. I.e. He doesn't immediately go to "I'm gonna call the cops!" or "I'm gonna sue!" Instead, he thinks "Is the other guy gonna call the cops?" or "Am I gonna get sued?" - Professor Stumblethumbs has already "called the cops" on Alex, who now faces this choice: go as a lamb to the slaughter, or lawyer up.